# Fait-on la liaison quand il y a une pause entre deux mots ?

Tags: prononciation, liaisons

Je voudrais savoir, s'il est nécessaire d'utiliser la liaison quand deux mots sont séparés par une pause (par exemple quand les mots sont séparés par une virgule dans une liste) ?

Note: J'essaie d'écrire seulement en français sur ce site et corrigez-moi si je fais des fautes, s'il vous plaît ! Je parle couramment en anglais, mais je préfère des réponses en français pour la pratique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La liaison est explicitement interdite quand il y a une pause entre les mots. On ne peut faire de liaison qu'**à l'intérieur d'un même groupe de souffle** dont les mots sont unis par le sens, ce qui, de fait, exclut toute marque de ponctuation qui oblige à faire une pause dans le débit de la voix.

Par exemple :

> J'ai mangé les pommes et les poires.

/le.pɔmz‿ele.pwaʁ/ ou /le.pɔm.ele.pwaʁ/  (liaison facultative entre « pommes et poires », rarement faite)

> J'ai mangé les pommes, et j'ai fini les poires.

/le.pɔm.e.ʒɛ.fini/ (liaison interdite entre « pommes et poires »)

Comment: Je vous remercie ! Maintenant, c'est clair.